# DecisionTreeRegressor Python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to complete an exercise question. I have to make use of boston dataset from python datasets package and Predict the housing price for first two samples of X_test set and print them.
I have tried all possible solutions that I could think of. Even though they are logically right, the environment is not accepting my code as the correct 
solution.

[Task1 question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcJ5n.png) is solved with the following code:

```
import sklearn.datasets as datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
np.random.seed(100)
boston = datasets.load_boston()
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(boston.data, boston.target,random_state=30)
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
```

[Task2 question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJBmo.png) I start with this line of code after keeping the above code as it is and just removing the print() statements

```
dt_reg = DecisionTreeRegressor().fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

But these are not being accepted as correct

First code:

```
y_pr = dt_reg.predict(X_test)
for i in y_pr[:2]:
    print(i)
```

Second Code:

```
y_pr = dt_reg.predict(X_test)
print(y_pr[0])
print(y_pr[1])
```

Third Code:

```
print(dt_reg.predict(X_test[:2]))
```

Comment: `print(dt_reg.predict(X_test[:2]))` should work. where can I find this test?

Comment: sorry, it is actually an internal corporate training for me.

Comment: Updated the answer @AshitaPatel I think your problem is likely to do with the random_state